# one liner to create a dictionnary with values of list an an other one. Is it possible?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, one-liner

I have the following code :

```
        rx_dctvals = {}
        for key, val in pos_table.items():
            rx_dctvals[re.compile("|".join(sorted([to_regex(v) for v in val], key=len, reverse=True)))] = key
```

Is it possible to make a one liner initialization for dict rx_dctvals using dict comprehension or other with the keys, values of pos_table dict ? I'm curious.
And this in one line ? In this one, i struggle with assignment:

```
for rx, repl in rx_dctvals.items():
     line = rx.sub(repl.replace('\\', '\\\\'), line)
```

Here is the entire code. This script changes POS (parts of speech of words from Penn Treebank to standard POS. It prints also NER (name entity recognition) of each word. It load a table of equivalence between pos from file and set a regex to change them.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!usr/bin/env python3

import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag
from nltk.chunk import tree2conlltags
import re
import sys

# fonction qui charge le premier dictionnaire de données (valeurs particulières, valeurs universelles, étiquètes POS et NER)
# c'est ce qui va servir de base pour la construction de nos regex.
def load_pos_table():

    try:
         
        with open('POSTags_PTB_Universal_Linux.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as universal:

            dict_pos = {}
            for sent in universal.readlines():
                for line in sent.splitlines():
                    cut = line.strip().split()
                    dict_pos[cut[1]] = dict_pos.get(cut[1], list()) + [cut[0]]

        return dict_pos

    except Exception as erreur:
        print(f'load_pos_table : {erreur}')

# fonction qui utilise un solide module regex pour supprimer les formes non standards (POS tag et NER) et les remplacer par les formes universelles
# cette fonction a l'avantage d’être générique et peut s’appliquer partout pour remplacer tout ce que l'on souhaite. Elle se base sur un dictionnaire.
def convert_format(line, pos_table):

    try:
        # comme il peut y avoir plusieurs formes non standards pour une forme universelle, on crée un regex d’agrégation en triant les valeurs par ordre décroissant de taille
        # pour éviter les conflits de remplacements. C'est la clé du dictionnaire. Sa valeur est l’étiquette universelle correspondante.
        rx_dctvals = {re.compile("|".join(sorted([to_regex(v) for v in val], key=len, reverse=True))):key for key, val in pos_table.items()}

        # on remplace séquentiellement nos valeurs non standards par leur équivalent universel avec notre liste de regex constituées précédemment.
        for rx, repl in rx_dctvals.items():
            line = rx.sub(repl.replace('\\', '\\\\'), line)
        
        return line

    except Exception as erreur:
        print(f'convert_tag: {erreur}')

# fonction pour bien définir les délimitations entre les mots dans les regex et pour échapper les caractères spéciaux.
def to_regex(x):

    r = []
    if x[0].isalnum() or x[0] == '_':
        r.append(r'(?<![^\W_])')
    else:
        if any(l.isalnum() or l=='_' for l in x):
            r.append(r'\B')
    r.append(re.escape(x))
    if x[-1].isalnum() or x[-1] == '_':
        r.append(r'\b')
    else:
        if any(l.isalnum() or l=='_' for l in x):
            r.append(r'\B')
    return "".join(r)

# fonction qui extrait les entités nommées en se basant sur le package ne_chunk et qui pos tag tous les mots également
# elle renvoie le résultat sous forme d'une liste de tuples.
def extract_entities(doc):

    # on tokenise et on extrait les entités nommées avec ne_chunk.
    return [tree2conlltags(ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)))) for sent in sent_tokenize(doc)]

def main():

    try:

        with open('wsj_0010_sample.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file, open('wsj_0010_sample.txt.ne.nltk', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as result_file:

            pos_table = load_pos_table()
            content = file.read()

            # on écrit un mot par ligne dans le fichier de résultats avec son POS et son NER (séparés par une tabulation (format universel ou standard)
            # grace à une list comprehension
            [[result_file.write(convert_format(f'{name}\t{tag}\t{ner}\n', pos_table)) for name, tag, ner in line] for line in extract_entities(content)]

    except Exception as error:
        print(f'main error : {error}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you can see a shorter way to do a task, tell me.

Comment: Why would you want a one-liner for this? Though it is possible, the current code is already quite complicated and should probably be refactored into multiple lines.

Comment: I'm just curious if it's possible

Comment: Read  up on dictionary comprehensions. That would simplify the dictionary construction part. Then consider factoring out a (testable) subroutine to build the re.

Comment: Yes Buddy, it works. Thx

Comment: is it possible to one line this 
`for rx, repl in rx_dctvals.items():
            line = rx.sub(repl.replace('\\', '\\\\'), line)`
For the first one i have a good one liner

Comment: i found it : `line = [line := rx.sub(repl.replace('\\', '\\\\'), line) for rx, repl in rx_dctvals.items()][-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Asked a comment, OP said it worked, turning it into an answer.

```
rx_dctvals = {re.compile("|".join(sorted([to_regex(v) for v in val], key=len, reverse=True))):key for key, val in pos_table.items()}
```

My only comment to make Is, the OP used `x[val] = key`, so I am doing so. But OP, I hope you know you use a key to open a chest of goodies.